# Return all tree family of a self associate table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a db structure like that:

Table: cat ( id,fk_cat ,name )

The field id_test pointing to the same table.

Ex.
Toy > Sports > Ball

When i search for Ball, i need also: Sports and Toy.
Where the first parent are fk_cat = null.
So:
id = 1,fk_cat = null, name = 'Toy'
id = 2,fk_cat = 1, name = 'Sports'
id = 3,fk_cat = 2, name = 'Ball'.

The question is, how i can handle all my family tree with single sql?
See on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bc257/2 to test

Comment: Is there a maximum number of nested child/parent relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent/child relationship you've described is known as the `Adjacency List Model` which can be difficult to traverse in MySQL (other RDBMS's can handle this using `Recursive Common Table Expressions`).

If you know the potential number of parent/children relationships, you can use `OUTER JOINs` to join the table on itself for each potential relationship (grandparent, parent, child, etc.).  Here's an example with up to 3 levels:

```
select 
  cc.id idchild, 
  ccparent.id idparent,
  ccgrandparent.id idgrandparent
from con_categoria cc
  left join con_categoria ccparent on cc.fk_cat = ccparent.id
  left join con_categoria ccgrandparent on ccparent.fk_cat = ccgrandparent.id
where cc.fk_cat = 378
```

- [Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bc257/8)

If you do not know the maximum number of potential children, then you'll need to look into using `Dynamic Sql` within a function or procedure.  Search SO and you should see some examples.

As a suggestion, if it's an option, consider using the `Nested Set Model`.  Much easier to query for hierarchical data.  Here is a good article on the subject and the comparison with the `Adjacency List Model`:

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/